# Parsing and storing data from digital signature in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: sharepoint-2013, digital-signature

I would like to know if there is a way to parse data from a digital signature and put it in a SharePoint list

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data would you like and store? Are you referring to SharePoint on-premises or Online?

We have a Connector for SharePoint on-prem that supports signing documents and list items within SharePoint. You can see a short video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xILkJwLaU8I):

Comment: I would like to store data that's on the digital signature. for example it could be the name, date or could be different information based on the field type.

Comment: Please provide more technical information:
- How is your digital signature represented (PKCS#7?)
- Is the data to be signed also stored in SharePoint? If so, in what format (PDF, Word, other?)
- Do you have SharePoint programming abilities?

Comment: The digital signature represented as pkcs#12 and would like to store the singnatre data on in sharepoint so that it's used as some sort of identifying factor for user. I also have some SharePoint programming knowledge as I am coming from java